# Tokenize data in Python(converting data into patterns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is like the one below:

```
Name      | City

Apple     | Tokyo
Papaya    | Pune
TimGru334 | Shanghai
236577    | Delhi
```

I need to iterate through each value and need to tokenise data in Python. To explain in detail:

- For the value 'Apple', this should be converted to 'ccccc' where c
  indicates a  character.
- For 'TimGru334', this should be converted to 'ccccccddd'
- Consider the value '236577', this should be converted to 'dddddd' where d indicates a digit/number.

Can someone help me out please?

P.S: I'm new to the platform, so please excuse me if I'm wrong in any manner.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) - first non numeric and then numeric values - order of values in lists is important:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace(['\D', '\d'], ['c','d'], regex=True)
print (df)
        Name      City
0      ccccc     Tokyo
1     cccccc      Pune
2  ccccccddd  Shanghai
3     dddddd     Delhi
```

If need replace all columns:

```
df = df.replace(['\D', '\d'], ['c','d'], regex=True)
print (df)
        Name      City
0      ccccc     ccccc
1     cccccc      cccc
2  ccccccddd  cccccccc
3     dddddd     ccccc
```

Comment: Is there anyway we can differentiate special characters like '-', '_' etc from letters?

Comment: @Shri - Can you test `df.replace([r'[^\w\s]+', '[a-zA-Z]', '\d'], ['.','c','d'], regex=True)` ?

Comment: What I understand from this is that, except for underscore and space, replace all special characters with '.'? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.replace`:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('\D', 'c').str.replace('\d', 'd')
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
        Name      City
0      ccccc     Tokyo
1     cccccc      Pune
2  ccccccddd  Shanghai
3     dddddd     Delhi
```

To do all columns, use @jezrael's answer, otherwise use:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\D', 'c').str.replace('\d', 'd'))
```

Comment: How do we iterate through columns here instead of hard coding the column name like 'Name' here?

Comment: df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('\D', 'c').str.replace('\d', 'd'))

This would either replace all at once if I'm not wrong. But how to iterate through columns one by one?

Comment: @Shri That's doing column by column

Comment: So x is like the parameter that passes the column value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196308/discussion-between-shri-and-u10-forward).